# htaccess redirect with parameters, pagination, and variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, pagination

I have looked everywhere for my exact situation, and I can't find it, so I'm here

I have tons of folders on my site - here are just a few

```
- birthdays
- home
- members
- new
- online
```

I want all my links to look like

```
- https://www.example.com/birthdays
- https://www.example.com/home
- https://www.example.com/members
- https://www.example.com/new
- https://www.example.com/online
```

In "birthdays", "new", and "online" I have one index.php file. It makes the link to the website look short and sweet, but having so many folders is cumbersome.

What I want to do is group together

```
- home
- members
- singlepages
```

Where "single pages" is all the files to all of the single pages, but I still want the URL to look short and sweet. I got halfway there

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /singlepages/$1.php [L]
```

Now the link to "https://www.example.com/birthdays" pulls the information from the "https://www.example.com/singlepages/birthdays.php" file, and it works great, HOWEVER, the "birthdays.php" file has URL parameters because of the pagination.

A normal link is "https://www.example.com/singlepages/birthdays.php?page=1"

1) How do I go about keeping that pagination working

2) How do I handle the the "page" variable in php? Is it the same "$_GET["page"];"

3) I have other pages with pagination and complex urls. Here's one for example

```
https://www.example.com/singlepages/search.php?city=Toronto&province=Ontario&Sex=Male&Color=Blue&Weight=200&height=183
```

Once I get the pagination working, how would I handle a URL like this?

Comment: Use the `[QSA]` flag to retain params. Add extra rules if you want to incorporate the `page=1` or other `city=` etc. into short URL params.

Comment: I have this for each page I want to redirect. Is this okay to use? or is this too much, or could be written better? There are 12 pages I need to redirect
`RewriteRule ^(birthdays.*)$ /singlepages/birthdays.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: You can have your short URL as: `https://www.example.com/birthdays?page=1` and your existing rule will still work.